# Let GridLayout automatically find optimal number of rows/columns

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

Is it possible to let `GridLayout` calculate the number of rows and columns without specifying one of them? I would just like child items to be wrapped around instead of clipped, and it seems there is no way a `LinearLayout` is able to do this.

Comment: `GridView` can do that, but the downside is that you have to create your items in code and use an `Adapter` instead of defining them in in XML directly.